# Copy files such that individual files gets copied to the folder having file name as a string within complete folder name

Tags: command-line, sed, find, copy, cp

I am using Cygwin as Linux shell,
I have following contents in my current working directory:

Files :

```
Abc.dat
123.dat
456.dat

Directories:
W_Abc_w 
W_123_w 
W_456_w

Now I want to copy files as below: 
Abc.dat -> W_Abc_w
123.dat -> W_123_w
456.dat -> W_456_w
```

How to achieve this in a single line linux command? Or a short shell script?

Comment: Off-topic and already cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553216/copy-files-such-that-individual-files-gets-copied-to-the-folder-having-file-name

Answer (score 2):

Using a Bash loop:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.dat; do
  sub="${f%.dat}"
  [ -d "W_${sub}_w" ] && cp -- "${f}" "W_${sub}_w"/
done
```

Comment: Thank you for making it not so sloppy and dirty. :D I'd thumbsup your edit if I could.